# How to get feature geometry?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a DrawFeature Control in OpenLayers app:

```
draw=new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(markers,OpenLayers.Handler.Point, {
        "title": "POI",
        "displayClass": "olControlDrawPoi"
})
app.mapPanel.map.addControl(draw);
```

Its work fine. Now i want to get window with created feature's geometry and attributes to edit them. How can i make it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967967/how-to-get-points-return-from-openlayers-control-drawfeature